# Mercurial Apache Web Access Gives Me 403 Forbidden Access

Tags: apache-2.2, forbidden, mercurial

after trying to enable mercurial apache web access on my Ubuntu Server 12.04 box, I've got a 403 Forbidden error when accessing http://my.site.com/mercurial with log:

> [Tue Sep 04 01:20:22 2012] [error] [client X.X.X.X] client
>   denied by server configuration: /mercurial/hgweb.cgi

I have added this to /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

> ```
>     ScriptAliasMatch ^/mercurial(.*) /mercurial/hgweb.cgi$1
>     <Directory /var/www/mercurial>
>             Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews ExecCGI
>             Options None
>             AllowOverride All
>             Order allow,deny
>             Allow from all
>             AuthType Basic
>             AuthName "Repositorio Mercurial"
>             AuthUserFile /mercurial/hgusers
>             Require valid-user
>     </Directory>
> ```

This is strange, but apache does't asks me for password when trying to access the web server folder

```
[web] 
style = gitweb

[collections] 
/mercurial/repositories = /mercurial/repositories
```

/mercurial/hgwebconfig.cgi (on filesystem)

> config = "/mercurial/hgweb.config"

I have linked /mercurial to /var/www/mercurial

Any advise will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is `/mercurial` a filesystem path, or is everything in `/var/www/mercurial`?

Comment: Edited, I have linked /mercurial to /var/www/mercurial on filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `/mercurial` (on the filesystem) as your script root, you need your authorization configuration there instead of on `/var/www/mercurial`, despite the fact that `/mercurial` symlinks to `/var/www/mercurial`.  From the [documentation of the `Options` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options):

> Even though the server follows the symlink it does not change the pathname used to match against `<Directory>` sections.

So, move your access controlling `<Directory>` block to be for `/mercurial` - and you'll need a `FollowSymLinks` on `/` as well.  (By the way, why does it have `Options None` right after the other `Options` directive?)

The symlink is making this a lot more complicated and confusing than it needs to be - I'd really recommend getting rid of that and using the `/var/www/mercurial` filesystem path, which will greatly simplify the situation.

Comment: OK, changed directory directive to this
    ScriptAliasMatch ^/mercurial(.*) /mercurial/hgweb.cgi$1
    <Directory /var/www/mercurial>
            Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Repositorio Mercurial"
            AuthUserFile /mercurial/hgusers
            Require valid-user
    </Directory>
Also moved /mercurial to /var/www and edited hgweb.copnfig and hgweb.cgi, restarted apache, and got forbidden again

Comment: orry, forgot to mention that i also have edited the line AuthUserFile /var/www/mercurial/hgusers  in directory directive

Comment: You'll still need `FollowSymLinks` enabled for `<Directory />` - please consider getting rid of the symlink mess altogether, it'll make this a lot easier.  Mind editing your question with your full current config?